# Trying to retrieve road speed limit from drivers current location

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I am trying to retrieve current speed limit of a given road location data is passed to the Open Street Maps api every 2-3 seconds as the vehicle is in motion.

I have tried the code below using [around] however it only outputs results when the radius is at least 2500 metres

i am seeking to have a an area that is closer to 10 meters to determine the current speed limit of the vehicles location.

If there is an alternative endpoint to achieve the above so that is more robust and responsive please advise

i am basically wanting to replicate what i see on navigation apps where the speed limit value updates within 1-2 seconds of a vehicle passing a new speed sign of value different to the previous speed zone being driven in

I would appreciate any assistance to resolve this issue.

https://lz4.overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?
data=[out:json];nodemaxspeed;out%20meta;

Comment: Overpass API usage policy only allows 10'000 requests per / day and app. Unless you set up your own Overpass API instance, this approach won't work anyway. Reference: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API --- besides, most maxspeed information is available as part of ways, while your query looks at nodes only.

Comment: Is this you? https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/69163/how-to-retrieve-maxspeed-of-any-road-location